# Как сделать что бы мышь на мониторе была слева?

Tags: монитор

купил монитор, поставил его слева от ноутбука и себя. Подключил через HDMI с типом широкий эркна. Почти все хорошо, но что бы мышка была на сам монитор я должен произвести вправо до конца экрана ноутбука, а как сделать что бы на монитор переходило когда я слева в край навожу.

P.S Доп. вопрос) ноут имеет интегрированный графический чипсет + Nvidia GTX 1050 TI. Нормально что монитор использует Intel UHD Graphics 630 вместо GTX 1050?

Comment: Зависит от операционной системы и используемой оболочки рабочего стола

Comment: это не в мониторе включается, а в ОС, если у вас windows 10. Ответы озвучивались на [habr для линукс](https://qna.habr.com/q/281348) и [microsoft для винды](https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/all/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA/b855f092-84e9-4b9a-8d8b-f09206a76520)